# What is the best way to bulk create in a through table?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

This is what my through table looks like:

```
class ThroughTable(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    society = models.ForeignKey(Society)
```

I am getting 2 lists containing ids of 2 model objects, which have to be added in my through table.

```
user_list = [1,2,5,6,9]
society_list = [1,2,3,4]
```

Here I want to create the entry in Through table for each possible pair in these 2 lists.

I was thinking about using using nested loops to iterate and create the objects in Through table, but it seems very naive, and has a complexity of n*n.

Is there a better approach to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Django provides a bulk_create() method to make entries in the database. It has optional argument **batch_size** because if you have millions of records, you can not enter all the records in one go so break the records in batches and enter the database.

`ThroughTable.objects.bulk_create(item, batch_size)`

Answer (score 0):

From [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-create):

> bulk_create(objs, batch_size=None, ignore_conflicts=False)
>
> This method inserts the provided list of objects into the database in an efficient manner >(generally only 1 query, no matter how many objects there are):

For your case first create a list with all the possible combinations and then save it.

```
items = []
for user, society in user_list:
    for society in society_list:
        item = ThroughTable(user=user, society=society)
        items.append(item)
ThroughTable.objects.bulk_create(items)
```

Comment: I was thinking the same, but can we reduce its complexity?